# Website resources still loading with https protocol

Tags: css, wordpress, apache, ssl

I've a really strange issue with my [website](http://blizzheart.com).

Several months ago my site had a SSL cert but I've stopped using it for some reasons. Since everything seems to works perfectly but few days ago a lot of my users tell me about issues with the website (broken layout they said).  Most of them solves this issue just with a hard refresh.

Since the last update of Chrome (yesterday) I'm facing the same issue where stylesheet doesn't load.

So I took a look in the source code of the page and I see that every resources (css, js, img, ...) are loaded in https protocol instead of http. It's why they can't load.

I don't know what happens, I'm facing this issue only with Chrome and I've of course clean cache, cookies, SSL certs, everything that I can clean and clean again.

In my `htaccess` nothing is rewriting http in https protocol, nothing in my wp-config too (I'm running a Wordpress install), and my subdomain tv.blizzheart.com on the same domain and using the same VHost works perfectly.

Today some users tell me that this error now occures in Firefox too. But on my side I'm facing this issue only with Chrome (I've tried Firefox and IE). Some of them said that this error occures only on the login page (blizzheart.com/login/)

I'm asking you because I fighting with this issue since yesterday and I can't understand what is happening.

Comment: Have you try put your path agnostic...maybe it help for you now -- example `href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"`

Comment: Did you go to menu  "Settings" -> "General" and updated both settings `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Luis and Zimmi. I've just solved this issue by adding these lines in my htaccess :

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader unset HTTPS
</IfModule>